# android 8-code color scheme

Tags: android, color-codes

I have seen some strange color codes used for android. I am used to RGB color codes such as

`<color name="white">#ffffff</color>`

Here you notice 6 hex values. However, some android color codes use 8 like so

`<color name="red">#ffff0000</color>`

I guess the extra two hex values are for transparency.

Is it the starting 2 or the ending 2 hex values that represent transparency? Also, does ff mean transparent and 00 opaque or vice versa? The closest thing I could find on http://android.com was [this](http://developer.android.com/samples/MediaRouter/res/values/colors.html). Links to resources will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You guessed right! The extra two digits are for transparency, and this format is called **aRGB**.

As evident from the name, the beginning two digits represent the alpha (or transparency) value, with **255 (ff) being fully opaque** and **0 (00) being fully transparent**.